# Receiving data type mismatch calling `EditorFor()`

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

When I call `@Html.EditorFor()` from a `*.cshtml` view, I am receiving the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `System.Boolean', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyType'.

That said, I am confident I am passing in a model of the correct type. My code looks something like this:

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyType, Model.MyType.Template, Model.MyType.Field)
```

`MyType` is the model bound to each of my `EditorTemplate` pages. The value of the `Template` property corresponds to the names of `EditorTemplate` pages, and the value of the `Field` property maps to *htmlField* name (both return strings).

Based on the error, I would expect that `Model.MyType` is returning a `Boolean` value instead of a `MyType` value, but I have confirmed that is not the case. I can even write out `@Model.MyType.GetType()` and see it's correctly retrieving a `MyType` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unintuitive, but this error will be thrown if the value for *templateName* doesn't map to a file name in the `EditorTemplates` directory. E.g., if `Model.MyType.Template` returns a string `MyTemplate`, but there isn't a corresponding `~/Views/Controller/EditorTemplates/MyTemplate.cshtml`.

In this particular case, there was an errant `Model.MyType.Template` value, which didn't map correctly to any `EditorTemplates`.

I imagine a similar error will occur with `DisplayFor()`.

Comment: Just name your template `~/Views/Controller/EditorTemplates/MyType.cshtml` to match the model and then its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyType)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Yes, that is precisely how this code was _intended_ to work. The problem is that if the `m.MyType` value fails to match a template (in this case, due to a bogus value) then it will throw an unintuitive type mismatch exception. The problem is resolved, but I posted it here in the hope that it will help others out; otherwise, given the error message, it's easy to misidentify the source.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I should also note, it was harder to isolate in my case _because_ the `templateName` value was being dynamically set, thus obscuring the bogus value. (In my actual application, this was part of a loop where most of the values were correct, but one was not.)

Comment: What I was getting at is that you do not need properties for `Template` and `Field` id you just follow the normal naming convention and name the template the same as the class.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Ah, yes, I understand you now. In my actual code, it's a bit more complicated as I have a 1:n relationship between templates and classes, and thus the `Template` property. But you're spot on; absent that requirement, your approach would be more elegant.